# How can I use Record/Playback syntax with StructureMap AutoMocker?

Tags: .net, tdd, mocking, structuremap, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to use the syntax

```
using(_mocks.Record())
{
   //...
}
using(_mocks.Playback())
{
   //...
}
```

with StructureMap RhinoAutoMocker?

In Jeremy Millers original post [AutoMocker in StructureMap 2.5](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/02/09/automocker-in-structuremap-2-5.aspx)  this seems possible since RhinoAutoMocker inherits MockRepository, but in version 2.5.2 of StructureMap this seems to be implemented in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this using a custom written AutoMocker and ServiceLocator.

```
public class RecordPlaybackRhinoAutoMocker<TARGETCLASS> : AutoMocker<TARGETCLASS> where TARGETCLASS : class
{
    private RecordPlaybackMocksServiceLocator MockRepository 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _serviceLocator as RecordPlaybackMocksServiceLocator; 
        } 
    }

    public RecordPlaybackRhinoAutoMocker()
    {
        _serviceLocator = new RecordPlaybackMocksServiceLocator();
        _container = new AutoMockedContainer(_serviceLocator);
    }

    public IDisposable Record()
    {
        return MockRepository.Record();
    }

    public IDisposable Playback()
    {
        return MockRepository.Playback();
    }
}

public class RecordPlaybackMocksServiceLocator : StructureMap.AutoMocking.ServiceLocator
{

    private readonly MockRepository _mocks;

    public RecordPlaybackMocksServiceLocator()
    {
        _mocks = new MockRepository();
    }

    public T PartialMock<T>(params object[] args) where T : class
    {
        return _mocks.PartialMock<T>(args);
    }

    public object Service(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _mocks.StrictMock(serviceType);
    }

    public T Service<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _mocks.StrictMock<T>();
    }

    public IDisposable Record()
    {
        return _mocks.Record();
    }

    public IDisposable Playback()
    {
        return _mocks.Playback();
    }
}
```

I still don't know if there is a built in way to do this. But this works and saves me from rewritting 1200 tests.

Comment: Did you ever find a "built in" way to do this?

Comment: @mxmissile: I didn't but it was quite a while ago. I haven't used StructureMap AutoMpcker since. A lot has changed and maybe there is a better way to do this now.

Comment: I ended up using this solution as I could not figure out a better way. If your not using SM Automocker what are you using?

Comment: @mxmissile: Project I'm working on now uses Autofac and not StructureMap so that's why I don't use Automocker.